# Decryption with CryptoStream using aes fails

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm writing two applications one encrypts files the other has to read. While the encryption and decryption in the first program works the second is not able to decrypt the file.

This is the code that encrypts the data:

```
using (Aes aes = getAes())
{
    ICryptoTransform aesEncrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor();
    doCrypt(filePath, aesEncrypt);
}
```

with doCrypt:

```
private void doCrypt(string filePath, ICryptoTransform aesCrypto)
{
    doCrypt(filePath, filePath, aesCrypto);
}
private void doCrypt(string sourceFilePath, string targetFilePath, ICryptoTransform aesCrypto)
{
    byte[] input = File.ReadAllBytes(sourceFilePath);
    FileStream cryptoFS = new FileStream(targetFilePath, FileMode.Create);
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(cryptoFS, aesCrypto, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    cryptoStream.Write(input, 0, input.Length);

    cryptoStream.Close();
    cryptoFS.Close();
}
```

and getAes:

```
public Aes getAes()
{
    Aes aes = AesCryptoServiceProvider.Create();
    MD5 keyHasher = MD5.Create();

    aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    aes.KeySize = 128;
    aes.BlockSize = 128;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    aes.Key = keyHasher.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pswdTB.Text));

    return aes;
}
```

**Note:** IV is not set, because aes runs in ECB-Mode, which does not use an IV

And this is the code to decrypt in the second application:

```
Aes aes = getAes();
//MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
//CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

//cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
//cs.Close();
//result = ms.ToArray();
//ms.Close();

FileStream cryptoFS = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Create);
CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(cryptoFS, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

cryptoStream.Close();
cryptoFS.Close();

aes.Dispose();
```

I need the result to be in the byte[] result, but for debugging purposes I replaced it with a file output.

**Edit** While I do get output, it's not decrypted properly.
This is a short peace of the resulting test.txt: "ꕾ㩈ႂ⤙͊꼥聓綨炌磌腼ꀽ鞍壃"
The file was an XML file before en- and decrypton.

The getAes here is a copy, the only difference is, that the key is supplied by another method.  But I checked the keys used are equal.

Comment: Whilst there are a lot of issues with your code, it seems to function as expected. You don't however indicate where/how the decryption "fails". This suggests there's something in the code you *haven't* provided that is the cause of whatever your problem is.

Comment: `aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write` should be `aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read`

Comment: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2014/01/20/diagnosing-issues-with-reversible-data-transformations/

Comment: @Iridium You are right, I have added the information on how it fails.
You mention a lot of issues, would you please explain the most severe of them to me?

Comment: @xanatos Wouldn't I use 'CryptoStreamMode.Read' with an input-stream?

Comment: @ChronosMOT You have to pass to the `new CryptoStream` the encrypted stream. Then you do a `cryptoStream.CopyTo(someOutputStream)` where `someOutputStream` will then contain the unencrypted output.

Comment: @xanatos it works, but why? in the first application I used doCrypt for both en- and decryption, and it worked just fine? Anyway, please post this as an answer, so I can accept it

Comment: @ChronosMOT Because on MSDN it is written so: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.cryptostream.aspx : *The stream on which to perform the cryptographic transformation.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET the `CryptoStream` has two "modes".

To encrypt you build it like:

```
CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(outputEncryptedStream, aesCrypto, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
```

to decrypt you build it like:

```
CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(inputEncryptedStream, aesCrypto, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
```

In both cases you must pass the encrypted/would be encrypted stream as the first parameter.

To encrypt something you can:

```
input.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
```

To decrypt something you can

```
cryptoStream.CopyTo(output);
```

(you don't need/can't use `FlushFinalBlock` to decrypt)

where `input` and `output` are the non-encrypted streams.

Comment: There's no requirement to use `CryptoStreamMode.Write` for encryption and `CryptoStreamMode.Read` for decryption, it is perfectly valid to use either mode for both encrypting and decrypting.

Comment: @Iridium Yes and no... If you look at the [reference source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/cryptostream.cs#L50) you can see that truly the `mode` is only used once: in the constructor to check that the passed stream can be read or written. So if you have a stream that can be both read and written, you can pass any value to the `CryptoStream` constructor, otherwise you have to pass the "correct" value.

Comment: I think it goes without saying that the mode has to match the type of stream used, my issue is with the fact that your answer suggests that encryption *must* use `Write` mode and decryption *must* use `Read` mode, when these are not the case.